# How do I make my PHP code dynamic?

Tags: php, forms

I am new to php and I am working on some forms (learning from W3 schools). I am used to HTML and CSS and having no logic at all, but I am starting a new project and I have to learn PHP and javascript.

```
<html>
<body>


<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
<br><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
<br><br>
Website: <input type="text" name="site">
<br><br>
Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="4" cols="40"></textarea>
<br><br>
Gender: <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"> 

<?php
// Must define the variables and give them no values
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";


function secure_input($data) 
{
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{
   $name = secure_input($_POST["name"]);
   $email = secure_input($_POST["email"]);
   $website = secure_input($_POST["site"]);
   $comment = secure_input($_POST["comment"]);
   $gender = secure_input($_POST["gender"]);
}



echo "<h1>Your Input:</h1>";
echo "Your name is: $name";
echo "<br>";
echo "Your email is $email";
echo "<br>";
echo "Your website is: $website";
echo "<br>";
echo "Comment: $comment";
echo "<br>";
echo "Your gender is: $gender";



?>
</html>
</body>
```

How do I get the echo statements at the end to display after I hit the input button (submit)?

Comment: put the echo statement in inside if condition, its by logic, I don't know whether it will work or not.

Comment: Didn't work because the form action "post" is constant, so the echo statements will always be displayed (unless of course something goes wrong and "post" is not returned)

Comment: change if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")  to if($_POST)  as @grim suggested, this may show some difference..  And another thing to add is try to study the basics better, W3 schools is not very good, try another tutorials

Comment: I agree with @SobinAugustine, W3 schools is not the best place to learn PHP but rather only for quick examples.

Comment: Uhm, Code academy, code school, there are plenty of pretty good ones but I've never learned PHP on those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of going about this:

```
if($_POST) {
  echo "<h1>Your Input:</h1>";
  echo "Your name is: $name";
  echo "<br>";
  echo "Your email is $email";
  echo "<br>";
  echo "Your website is: $website";
  echo "<br>";
  echo "Comment: $comment";
  echo "<br>";
  echo "Your gender is: $gender";
}
```

You could do additional checks to see if your variables have been set.

I would actually go with:

```
if($_POST) {
  $name = secure_input($_POST["name"]);
  $email = secure_input($_POST["email"]);
  $website = secure_input($_POST["site"]);
  $comment = secure_input($_POST["comment"]);
  $gender = secure_input($_POST["gender"]);

  echo "<h1>Your Input:</h1>";
  echo "Your name is: $name";
  echo "<br>";
  echo "Your email is $email";
  echo "<br>";
  echo "Your website is: $website";
  echo "<br>";
  echo "Comment: $comment";
  echo "<br>";
  echo "Your gender is: $gender";
}
```

Comment: Where is the "$_POST" coming from? Is that a statement that calls the data?

Comment: @HiveVoltage $_POST is a Global PHP variable that is set and filled with POST data from HTTP POST requests. Since you use w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp

Comment: Life! How grandiose! ;)